# Why does ranges::for_each return the function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, language-design, std-ranges

The legacy `std::for_each` returns function as the standard *only* requires `Function` to meet *Cpp17MoveConstructible* according to [[alg.foreach]](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms#alg.foreach-1):

> ```
> template<class InputIterator, class Function>
>   constexpr Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
> ```
>
> *Preconditions*: `Function` meets the *Cpp17MoveConstructible* requirements.
>
> [Note: `Function` need not meet the requirements of *Cpp17CopyConstructible*. end note]

This is reasonable since the user may want to reuse the function after the call.

The parallel version of `for_each` has no return:

> ```
> template<class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIterator, class Function>
>   void for_each(ExecutionPolicy&& exec,
>                 ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
>                 Function f);
> ```
>
> *Preconditions*: `Function` meets the *Cpp17CopyConstructible* requirements.

This is because the standard requires `Function` to meet the *Cpp17CopyConstructible*, so returning the function is unnecessary as the user can *freely* create a copy if they want on the call side.

I noticed that `ranges::for_each` also returns the function:

> ```
> template<input_iterator I, sentinel_for<I> S, class Proj = identity,
>          indirectly_unary_invocable<projected<I, Proj>> Fun>
>   constexpr ranges::for_each_result<I, Fun>
>     ranges::for_each(I first, S last, Fun f, Proj proj = {});
> ```

However, the function signature already requires `Fun` to satisfy `indirectly_unary_invocable` which already guarantees that it is copy constructible.

The question is, why does the `ranges::for_each` still return the function? What's the point of doing this?

Comment: Interesting question.  It might just be to make it easier to drop in as a replacement for `std::for_each`.  But that's pure speculation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It returns the functor because that allowed some clever tricks with stateful functors back in the day (in C++98, I assume). You don't see those often today, because lambdas are usually more straightforward.

Here's an example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct EvenCounter
{
    int count;

    EvenCounter() : count(0) {}

    void operator()(int x)
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0)
            count++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int num_even = std::for_each(array, array+5, EvenCounter()).count;
    std::cout << num_even << '\n';
}
```

> This is reasonable since the user may want to reuse the function after the call.

I think the logic is backwards here. The function isn't required to be copyable simply because there's no reason for `for_each` to copy it.

If you have a non-copyable (or even non-movable) function, you can pass it by reference using `std::ref` to avoid copies/moves, so you don't win anything here from the algorithm returning the function back to you.

There was no `std::ref` in C++98, but there was also no move semantics, so `for_each` couldn't have worked with non-copyable functors in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the guess. However, I don't see the need to specifically allow this kind of trickery in modern C++, especially for more powerful C++20 constraint functions. Note that `ranges::for_each` does not just return fun, so the spelling will be `ranges::for_each(...).fun.count` in your case, which makes even less sense.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I guess some people still like this trick, or at least the committee members thought so.

Answer (score 12):

> The question is, why does the `ranges::for_each` still return the function? What's the point of doing this?

The answer here is simply: all `std::ranges::meow` algorithms simply either (a) return the same thing as `std::meow` (e.g. `count`, `find`, etc.) or (b) additionally return the newly advanced input iterator (e.g. `copy`) if that would be a useful thing to return. Technically some of the value-returning functions (like, again, `count`) could also potentially benefit from returning the end iterator, but that's a big hit to ergonomics for those, so that didn't happen.

Notably, they all either (a) preserve or (b) add to the existing return types.

Nobody wanted to go through and actually *change* return types of algorithms and make additional design decisions like that on top of the massive body of work that Ranges is already. As [our favorite cat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77194949/2069064) already points out, `std::for_each` returning the function object itself is already kind of unnecessary in C++11 since you can accomplish the stateful thing by simply using `std::ref` if you really want - but it doesn't seem worthwhile to deprecate this and change `std::for_each` to return `void`, and then doubly it doesn't seem worthwhile to have `std::ranges::for_each` be the one<sup>†</sup> algorithm that actually *differs* in behavior from its `std::` counterpart.

---

<sup>†</sup> Well, technically not the only one. `std::ranges::copy` specifies how many iterator increments happen while `std::copy` does not. I happened to touch on this a bit in my CppNow talk this year: [`take(5)`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvi0cl8ccNQ).

Comment: *"... and then doubly it doesn't seem worthwhile to have `std::ranges::for_each` be the one† algorithm that actually differs in behavior from its `std::` counterpart."* I wonder why they felt so reluctant about this difference in behavior, they don't seem to have this problem when designing the type-trait counterparts in the form of concepts (e.g: `std::assignable_from<std::string&, char>`).

Comment: @303 Those two things have nothing to do with each other? Turns out people can make different decisions about different questions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straightforward use case:

```cpp
struct sum {
  int total;
  auto operator ()(const int x) { total += x ; }
};

int main() {
  const auto v = std::vector{ 1, 2, 3, };
  const auto [i, f] = std::ranges::for_each(v, sum());
  std::cout << f.total;
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dxscMM8W1)
NB: I noticed there was already [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77194949/9282847) when I was done writing this…

I'm currently looking for the actual rationale behind this choice, I'll update this when I have an answer from a reputable source.